# Change values in column after nsmallest pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a value (distance) and a label (cluster), I'm taking the first n values with nsmallest and trying to assign them a different label, but nothing seems to work.

Last try was:
`df.nsmallest(1000, 'distance', "all")["cluster"].apply(lambda x: 5)`

That returns the value 5 for the 1000 smallest distances, but nothing change in df.

I've also tried
`df.nsmallest(1000, 'distance', "all")["cluster"] = 5`  
that raises no errors but again df doesn't change.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do with the `index` of the `nsmallest` and `loc`

```
df.loc[df.nsmallest(1000, 'distance', "all").index, 'cluster'] = 5
```